# Why Kata's guest kernel is bigger than Gvisor's, although it has been optimized

Tags: linux-kernel, containers, sandbox, kata-containers, gvisor

Kata uses an optimized Linux kernel as a guest kernel and gvisor uses an application kernel.

Why Kata's guest kernel is bigger than Gvisor's, although it has been optimized?